# php - Example data from Google Analytics API response

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I need to create my custom view for data from Google Analytics but I don't have any access to any data for API tests. Is there any place where can I find sample data for this response?

Comment: There is a [Demo account](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6367342?hl=en). I'm wondering if this is off topic... There are other SE sites, like [webmaster](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) and [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Yes, but API is disabled for it. "You cannot use the demo account with the Analytics Reporting API."

Comment: Didn't know that